# Filtering the Firestore documents with more than one query

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to access the list of doctors that belong to 'someDepartment' and work for 'someHospital' from the given data in `hospitalnames` and `docnames` collection in Firestore.

`hospitalnames` collection:

[image: hospitalname]

`docnames` collection :

[image: docnames]

For example, doctors working in `SJMC` hospital in `Gynecology` department will be ['Dr. Jade Orman', 'Dr. Lia Reimers, 'Dr. Smith Johanson']

My ultimate goal is to show this list inside a `DropDownButton`.

**This was my implementation till now [this returns null for some reason]**

```
 List<String>? doctors = [];
 Future<dynamic> _getDoctors() async {
   var doctorNames = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('docnames')
    .where('hospital', arrayContains: _hospital) // `_hospital` is set from hospital dropdown
    .where("department", isEqualTo: _department) // `_department` is set from department dropdown
    .get()
    .then((value) => value.docs.map((e) => e.data()['name']).toList());
     doctors = doctorNames.cast<String>();
    return doctorNames;
  }
```

**I also tried this approach [returns null too!]**

```
 List<String>? doctors = [];
 Future<dynamic> _getDoctors() async {
   var doctorNames = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('docnames')
    .orderby(_hospital, descending: false) // `_hospital` is set from hospital dropdown
    .where("department", arrayContains: _department) // `_department` is set from department dropdown
    .get()
    .then((value) => value.docs.map((e) => e.data()['name']).toList());
     doctors = doctorNames.cast<String>();
    return doctorNames;
  }
```

This is the error I am getting:

[image: Error faced]

My app has 3 `DropDownButton`:

- the first one shows the list of hospitals directly,
- the second one shows the departments present on the **Hospital** selected on the previous `DropDFirestore, I tried it but it didn't work out.

[image: Index on Firebase]

Please point out anything I can try to do better for implementing this kind of feature [`Dynamic Dependent DropDrownButton list`] (Successive dropdown depends on the previous dropdown items selected)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first param in `.where()` is the field name and not the value you are looking for. So `.where(_hospital, isEqualTo: 'SJMC')` will be looking for a field name that is equal to value of `_hospital`.

Then in your documents, "department" seems to be a string and "hospital" seems to be an array. So ideally you would be using `arrayContains` on hospital field and `isEqualTo` on department but it's the other way at the moment. Try refactoring the code as shown below:

```
 List<String>? doctors = [];

 // Can add these 2 for testing
 print(_hospital);
 print(_department);

 Future<dynamic> _getDoctors() async {
   var doctorNames = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('docnames')
    .where("hospital", arrayContains: _hospital) // `_hospital` is set from hospital dropdown
    .where("department", isEqualTo: _department) // `_department` is set from department dropdown
    .get()
    .then((value) => value.docs.map((e) => e.data()['name']).toList());
     doctors = doctorNames.cast<String>();
    return doctorNames;
  }
```

Comment: Understood the mistake did the changes now I get and error
`Expected a value of type 'String', but got one of type 'Null'`

Comment: What error @OddlyGhost ?

Comment: `Expected a value of type 'String', but got one of type 'Null'`

Comment: let me edit the question and put the error for better understanding

Comment: Edited the Question with the error plz check

Comment: @OddlyGhost can you try commenting `doctors = doctorNames.cast<String>();` line once? Also it might be best to post a new question for this with relevant details and screenshots of code.

Comment: Sure I would do it